# Using a driver without .inf and .cat

Tags: windows, mfc, driver

I am upgrading an OLD application, and I need to add a driver, which hopefully works.

I only have the .sys for this driver, is it possible to make my MFC application work just having that ?

As of right now, this is the code that I have...summarized.

```
    m_hDevice = CreateFile("C:\\Windows\\system32\\drivers\DRIVERNAME",
                         GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                         FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                         NULL,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,
                         0,
                         NULL);

        bResult = DeviceIoControl(m_hDevice,
                     IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_MODEMSTATUS,
                     NULL,
                     0,
                     &ulModemStatus,
                     sizeof(ulModemStatus),
                     &nLength,
                     NULL);
DWORD error = GetLastError();
```

So, error = 87 which is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

P.S. These drivers were made for Windows NT. Should they work ? Do I have a problem if I don't have .inf and .cat files to properly installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the driver control an actual piece of hardware? If so, is that hardware listed in the device manager?

Comment: Yes, it is going to control an actual piece of hardware. It's a simple bit on/off pretty much.
No, it is not listed in the device manager...as of right now on my installer I have my application and just put the .sys in system32/drivers...for which I'm not sure if it's the correct thing...never worked with drivers before

Comment: You can't install or run a driver just by opening the file.  But it is sometimes possible to install a driver using `sc create` on the command line or the CreateService API.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the device is not enumerated in the device manager means that you've probably got a "Legacy Driver" (i.e. doesn't participate in Plug and Play), so an inf file won't do you any good. Your only hope is to open Device Manager, then from the Action menu, select "Add legacy hardware" and follow the prompts.

Note: you will need to be running 32-bit windows for this to work at all.

More information can be found here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851685.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just noticed that this driver does not work on the previous version of the program that I'm upgrading. I'll just have to write the driver...
Thanks for the help again.

P.S. Add Legacy Hardware also asks me for the .inf file, and yeah it's really old it's meant to be for Windows NT.